# php download a file server to client to a specific folder on the client side

Tags: php, server, download, client

This code

```
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.mp3');
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
    readfile('test.mp3');
```

Will download a file to the client directory nominated in the browser settings, usually the downloads folder.

Is there any way to nominate a specific folder on the client side so that instead of the downloads folder, I download to the /backup/another_directory/on_the_local_pc folder

Comment: I doubt it. Downloading is performed by browser.

Comment: You can't decide where the client should store the files it downloads. That's 100% up to the client, which is a good thing. If not, sites could scatter files all around your file system, which would be horrible and very insecure.

Comment: That would make the browser vulnerable. Imagine you could write to `c:\windows` or `~`.